# Altair - plotting custom colors

Tags: python, altair

I have custom colors I'd like to plot with `altair`.

Say, `color = '#CE1317'`:

```
bar = alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
        alt.X('Performance Indicator:N', title=""),
        alt.Y(f'{player[0]}:Q', title="", sort='-x', scale=alt.Scale(domain=(0.0, 2.5))),
        color=f'{color}:N',
        tooltip=[f'{player[0]}:Q']
        ).properties(
        height=600,
        width=alt.Step(40)  # controls width of bar.
        )
```

---

But this is not working. It plots blue. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this using a value encoding:

```
bar = alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
    alt.X('Performance Indicator:N', title=""),
    alt.Y(f'{player[0]}:Q', title="", sort='-x', scale=alt.Scale(domain=(0.0, 2.5))),
    color=alt.value(color),
    tooltip=[f'{player[0]}:Q']
).properties(
    height=600,
    width=alt.Step(40)  # controls width of bar.
)
```

Comment: thank you. but it only works with `color=alt.value(f'{color})`. Must remove `:N`